# Lazy loading of images while using angular dynamic ng-src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, image

There are many image tags across the application and ng-src is dynamic in each image like:

```
<div ng-controller="load_product">
<img ng-controller="image_controller" ng-src="{{product.image}}" />
</div>
<div ng-controller="load_brand">
<img ng-controller="image_controller" ng-src="{{brand.image}}" />
</div>
```

Now I want to implement lazy loading of images using image_controller used on each image. For this, there are two events available in image_controller when image load or when error occurs on image loading using

```
 $($element).load(function () {......})
 $($element).error(function () {......}).
```

For lazy loading, my approach is to replace src of the image to a dummy 1px image if it is not in the viewport and store original src in another attribute **lazysrc** and change to original src if the image is in viewport i.e. copy value from lazysrc to src if the image in the viewport.

But for this i need a event when ng-src of image is resolved but request for image is not send by browser.

Note: load_product and load_brand controllers load the data after some events. So, I need to copy the src to lazysrc when data is loaded , ng-src is resolved but request of the image is not sent. I want to stop this request after data loading and ng-src resolved.

I don't want to change the HTML in any case as it is a thousand of pages application.